# PHP webscraper does not produce errors nor start the loop/create output

Tags: php, web-scraping, request, goutte

I am writing a web scraper in PHP using gitpod. After a while I have managed to solve all problems. But even though no problems are left, the code does not open the browser nor produce any output.
Does anybody have an idea why that could be the case?

```
<?php
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
}
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Goutte\Client();

// Create a new array to store the scraped data
$data = array();

// Loop through the pages
if ($client->getResponse()->getStatus() != 200) {
    echo 'Failed to access website. Exiting script.';
    exit();
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    // Make a request to the website
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives_de?page=' . $i);

    // Find all the initiatives on the page
    $crawler->filter('.initiative')->each(function ($node) use (&$data) {
        // Extract the information for each initiative
        $title = $node->filter('h3')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->attr('href');
        $description = $node->filter('p')->text();
        $deadline = $node->filter('time')->attr('datetime');

        // Append the data for the initiative to the data array
        $data[] = array($title, $link, $description, $deadline);
    });
    // Sleep for a random amount of time between 5 and 10 seconds
    $sleep = rand(5,10);
    sleep($sleep);
}

// Open the output file
$fp = fopen('initiatives.csv', 'w');

// Write the header row
fputcsv($fp, array('Title', 'Link', 'Description', 'Deadline'));

// Write the data rows
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

// Close the output file
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: `does not open the browser`...what do you mean? A web scraper generally uses its own HTTP client, not a browser. Goutte is a "headless" browser, meaning it has no user interface, it's controlled only through the program code. It's unclear what you were expecting to happen, or why.

Comment: If it doesn't produce any output in the CSV file though, that's presumably because what was downloaded didn't contain any of the content your filter code is looking for. Have you done any debugging? Have you checked what it actually downloaded?

Comment: ok, thanks. I was not aware that it is headless :)

Comment: the output stays empty

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte doesn't mention any requirement for a browser, or any suggestion of it. And the tag for goutte here at SO describes it as headless specifically. I don't believe it's a secret :-)

Comment: Ok anyway if the output is empty then you'll need to do some debugging and analysis as I described, to work out why it's not finding the elements your code expects.

Comment: SHow us what you are looking for in the HTML and maybe we can point you in the right direction